# How can I access ViewModel from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

Is there any way I can access a ViewModel via Javascript?

I have a situation where I have a number of partials (representing different ways of inputting data.) Each of these then performs some javascript on the input.

RadioButton Lists, buttons and even text boxes are straightforwards.

But I can't get the dropdown list to work.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Answers", new SelectList(@Model, "Id", "AnswerText"), "[Please Select]")

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Answers').change(function () {
    var text = ($('#Answers option:selected').text());
    var id = ($('#Answers option:selected').val());
   // var nextId = @Model.Find(x => x.Id == id).NextId;

    AnswerSelected(text, id, nextId);
})
</script>
```

So the issue is on the commented line. My AnswerSelected code needs 3 parameters. Is there any way of passing my viewmodel into the javascript, as the only other way I can see I could do this would be to change the Select Id field to be "Id_NextId", and then add in more js to parse this into the 2 seperate parameters.

Comment: No, the way you're approaching the problem is impossible.  The `change` function will only occur after the full page is loaded.  You'll just have the DOM to work with - the concept of a ViewModel is lost once you reach the client.

Comment: With that said, you could load your model into a javascript array on page load, then you'd have an object to work with on the client.  Or you could use AJAX to call back to the server.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll take a look. (I'll probably load the data into an array on the client), or else I have some of these partials doing all teh work client side, and some using a mix, and I lose consistency :)